# how to make json object in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have all values from aspx page. now I want to prepare following json values by picking up from the control values of aspx where user has inputted and want to submit to other application in same format.For that below is the example I want to make exact copy as like below.

```
 var tempk = {
        "requestTypeCode": "PRE_DETERMINATION",
        "billingProvider": {
            "npi": "1234567893",
            "ein": "111222333",
            "payerAssignedProviderId": "XYZ321"
        },
        "patient": {
            "relationshipCode": "01",
            "lastName": "Smith",
            "firstName": "Bob",
            "stateCode": "FL",
            "birthDate": "1980-02-12",
            "genderCode": "M"
        },
        "payer": {
            "id": "BCBSF"
        },
        "submitter": {
            "id": "123456789",
            "lastName": "SUBMITTER"
        },
        "subscriber": {
            "memberId": "JDH001",
            "groupName": "ASDF 1-2",
            "groupNumber": "12312412"
        },
        "claimInformation": {
            "placeOfServiceCode": "11",
            "diagnoses": [
              {
                  "qualifierCode": "ABK",
                  "code": "J3089"
              }
            ],
            "serviceLines": [
              {
                  "procedureCode": "92523",
                  "quantity": "100",
                  "amount": "250",
                  "fromDate": "2016-05-10"
              }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Can you assist me how with the C# code will achieve?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [c].

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: For what is JSON an acronym? **Javascript Object Notation.**. That should be a hint for you. Create a C# object -- perhaps a `struct` made up of other `struct`s -- representing this information. Then look up "how to turn C# objects into JSON".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json from nuget

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json